# Youtube iFrame javascript API onYouTubeIframeAPIReady not firing

Tags: api, iframe, youtube

This is from the Youtube API docs:

"As mentioned in the Getting started section, instead of writing an empty  element on your page, which the player API's JavaScript code will then replace with an  element, you could create the  tag yourself."

But I cannot get the API to callback to my javascript. Any help would be great.

Here's my HTML code:

```
 <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1_QO8LoGNpc?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        alert("hey");
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
         // height: '720',
         // width: '1280',
         // videoId: '1_QO8LoGNpc',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I can get it to work with using javascript creating the iframe but not setting the iframe on the page. HELP!

Answer (score 2):

Function ***onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()*** should be defined before loading  https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api.

Here is the idea:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1_QO8LoGNpc?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe> 

    <script>
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            alert("hey");
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
             // height: '720',
             // width: '1280',
             // videoId: '1_QO8LoGNpc',
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

**Why?** Because **iframe_api** will call this function after being loaded. In your case iframe_api was loaded before.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

But your code works. See it here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aXLA2/

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1_QO8LoGNpc?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe> 

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```